# How to redirect output of Win32::Process command to text file?

Tags: perl, winapi, win32-process

I am running a command in a Perl script using Win32::Process, and I need to redirect the output of that command to a text file. After doing a bit of research, this is what I am trying:

```
use Win32::Process;

open (OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT");
open (OLDERR, ">&STDERR");
my $file = "output.txt";
open (STDOUT, ">$file");
open (STDERR, ">&STDOUT");

my $timeout = 1000 * 60; # 60 second timeout
my $proc;
my $exit;
my $exe = "C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe";
Win32::Process::Create($proc, $exe, "echo hello from process", 1, DETACHED_PROCESS, ".");
$proc->Wait($timeout);
$proc->GetExitCode($exit);

system("echo hello from system"); # To verify that the redirect is working

close (STDOUT);
close (STDERR);
open (STDOUT, ">&OLDOUT");
open (STDERR, ">&OLDERR");
close (OLDOUT);
close (OLDERR);
```

Unfortunately this is not working. In the output.txt file, I only get "hello from system". Is there a way to accomplish what I want using Win32::Process?

The reason I am using Win32::Process rather than backticks is because my command sometimes crashes, and I need to provide a timeout in order to kill it if neccessary. The ->Wait() function of Win32::Process allows me to do this.

I would rather have a solution using Win32::Process, as I am limited to which modules I have access to. However, if this really cannot be done, I would welcome an example solution using some other module.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying `DETACHED_PROCESS` when you start the process. The effect of this is the following:

> `DETACHED_PROCESS` `0x00000008`
>
> For console processes, the new process does not inherit its parent's console (the default).

See [Process Creation Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx).

The reason passing `"echo hello from process"` as the command line to `Win32::Process` doesn't work is because `echo` is a `cmd.exe` builtin. You need to instead use the command line `'cmd /c "echo hello from process"'` as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Which qw(which);
use Win32;
use Win32::Process;

open OLDOUT, ">&STDOUT";
open OLDERR, ">&STDERR";

my $file = 'output.txt';

open STDOUT, ">$file";
open STDERR, ">&STDOUT";

my $timeout = 15 * 1_000;
my ($proc, $exit);
my $exe = which 'cmd.exe';
Win32::Process::Create($proc, $exe, 'cmd /c "echo hello from spawned process"', 1, 0, '.');
$proc->Wait($timeout);
$proc->GetExitCode($exit);

print "Doing work ...\n"; sleep 3;

print "Spawned process exited with $exit\n";

close STDERR;
close STDOUT;
open STDERR, ">&OLDERR";
open STDOUT, ">&OLDOUT";
close OLDERR;
close OLDOUT;
```

Contents of `output.txt`:

```
$ perl main.pl

$ type output.txt
hello from spawned process
Doing work ...
Spawned process exited with 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have tested it with $exe = which 'gnatmake', and the command replaced by "gnatmake -v", and the output is correctly written to output.txt. I have also removed the forked process because I believe this is unnecessary. It seems like my real problem was with the echo command, because I still cannot get it to work with this. But since I was only using this for testing, I do not care.

Comment: I have tested this and it is working perfectly. Thank you for your help.